# how to add a character into a textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox

i would like to add a character to a text-box that separates two characters from two like this :

```
22:11
```

so when the user enters 22 it auto switch to after the separator and then the user can enter 11.

how can i do this , thanks.

Comment: first tell us that you are using ASP .Net textbox control or HTML  input text control???

Comment: Why not just use two text boxes limited to two characters with a colon in the middle?

Comment: @Kishan Gajjar - using an asp.net textbox not an input

Comment: @Alex - the textbox is already limited and i tried to add a colon but the it doesn't auto jump to after the colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can could using the [Masked Input plugin](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/how-to-mask-input-with-jquery/) with pattern "99:99"

[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/D58fx/)

For asp.net, if you are using [ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/), you can use the [MaskedEdit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) extension.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
$('#textbox').keyup(function(){
  if ($(this).val().length == 2) {
    $(this).val( $(this).val() + ':');
  }
});
```

just keep in mind that this example uses `.keyup()` method which is invoked when the user releases the button so if he releases the button when the value is 222 it won't work

**edit:**

and this is an improved example using regex:

```
$('#textbox').keyup(function(){
    t = $(this);
    v = t.val();
    pattern = /^(\d{2})(\d*)$/;
    if (v.match(pattern)) {
        t.val(v.replace(pattern, '$1:$2'));
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JDb2H/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'MaskedEdit' control instead of a textbox. Use '99:99' as the mask.

More info here:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Use%20the%20MaskedEdit%20Control.ashx

Comment: i tried this `<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server"
           TargetControlID="TimeBox"
           Mask="99:99"
           MessageValidatorTip="true"
           MaskType="Time"
           InputDirection="RightToLeft"
           AcceptNegative="Left"
           ErrorTooltipEnabled="true" >
    </asp:MaskedEditExtender>` but it didnt work

Comment: Do you use the ASP.NET AJAX control toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

- Bind keyUp event of textbox
- in the triggered function check for a RegExp (e.g. [0-2][0-9])
- if match add to val() the ':' string